# Angular 1.3.15 + cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I use angular 1.3.15 and $cookies v1.3.5
I put "user_id" cookies for domain /app/ and it's ok.
But if i change route for instance /app/history/ and again put cookies i'll have 2 cookies "user_id" for 2 domain (/app/ and /app/hostory).

How can i delete all cookies for all domains?

I use these commands for putting and getting cookies

```
$cookies.user_id = 1;
var user_id = $cookies.user_id;
delete $cookies.user_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
angular.forEach($cookies, function (i, c) {
    $cookieStore.remove(c);
});
```

But $cookieStore is deprecated (since v1.4.0). So, please upgrade.
All the best.

Comment: Yeah. Better go for upgrade. In upgrade you can simply do this task.

Comment: I updated app, but the problem is still here. I try to delete all cookies like that   var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
  angular.forEach(cookies, function (v, k) {
   $cookies.remove(k,{path: "/app"});
  });